# F# Create list of multiples of x?

Tags: list, f#, factors

I want to create a list that is the multiples of a number.  For example [2; 4; 6; 8; 10] would be the multiples of 2 between 0 and 10.

How would I dynamically create such a list of the multiples of x?  Is it possible to do it without setting an upper bound?

One way to do it would be to create a list between 0 and some crazy large number and then filter it using the mod function. Trying to test this, creating a list of 0 to some crazy large number caused an out of memory exception (after a 30 second or so wait).

I feel like F# has some super simple and awesome way to build such a list but I'm too much of a newb to know what it is, yet. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces an infinite sequence of multiples:

```
let multiples n = Seq.unfold (fun i -> Some(i, i + n)) n

multiples 3 |> Seq.take 3 //seq [3; 6; 9]
```

This is a bit more code, but faster:

```
let multiples n =
  let rec loop i =
    seq {
      yield i
      yield! loop (i + n)
    }
  loop n
```

It's basically equivalent to the following C#:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Multiples(int n) {
    int i = n;
    while (true) {
        yield return i;
        i += n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sequences (IEnumerables) give the laziness you want here:

```
let multiplesOfN n =
    seq {
        for i in 1 .. 1000000 do
            yield i * n
    }

let first6multsof3 = 
    multiplesOfN 3 |> Seq.take 6

printfn "%A" (first6multsof3 |> Seq.toList)
```

or with your filter-mod strategy:

```
seq { 1 .. 1000000} |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x%3=0) |> Seq.take 6 |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: StackOverflow.  The place where you ask a question and have the exact answer you're looking for moments later.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ firstValue..Step..endValue]
```

[ 2..2..10] => [2; 4; 6; 8; 10]

other way

```
Seq.initInfinite id |> Seq.map (((+) 1) >> ((*) 2))
```

Comment: +1. Or `seq{2..2..10}` for lazy sequence. Shame F# doesn't have open-ended range expressions (like `[2,4..]` in Haskell)

Comment: range for int ,Limit max System.Int32.MaxValue :2147483647. same by unfold

Answer (score 1):

```
List.init 10 ((*) 3)
val it : int list = [0; 3; 6; 9; 12; 15; 18; 21; 24; 27]
```

You can play with the arguments and `Seq.skip` to get whatever you need.

For example, for `[2; 4; 6; 8; 10]`:

```
List.init 6 ((*) 2)
|> List.tail
```

Or:

```
List.init 6 ((*) 2)
|> Seq.skip 1
|> List.ofSeq
```